# "Transition to" vs. "transition into"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-into

What is the correct phrasing:

> transition into

vs

> transition to

Can you explain why?

Here’s the context:

> In partnering with us, businesses can transition to/into a digital publication etc.

Comment: More context is need, but, at first look, I would say "into" fits better after "transition". Please, provide some example sentences.

Comment: As Carlo_R says, we could use a bit more context. But it might not make much difference, since I can't easily think of contexts where one or the other is automatically "better". FWIW, ["to" is about 15 times more common than "into"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transition+into%2Ctransition+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) in Google Books, so I'm tempted to advise just sticking with the majority usage if you're not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel "transition into" implies more significance to the occurrence. "Transition to" might be be a lesser or perhaps more common change.

Like the difference between the act of adapting to a given circumstance and the act of changing one's nature.

- She managed the transition to public school quite well.
- The caterpillar will make the transition into a butterfly.

Answer (score 4):

Since I'm old hat, I suggest that 'transition' is not yet a verb and so, neither example is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

"Transitioning to" implies that the subject is going from one place to another (perhaps instantly) while "Transitioning into" implies that the subject is going through a process to become, or to do, something else.

I believe "into" is what you would use to describe how a business can become something better with the process of combining with your institution.